# htaccess - URL Rewrite to rewrite specific URLs but allow one subdir URL

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, url-rewriting

We are using a CMS (Magento) where we are looking to have all of the current customer dashboard links redirect to the homepage, however when doing this with simple 301 rewrites, it unfortunately affects the log out link as well, which is an extension of some of the other customer dashboard links.

Within the root htaccess, we simply did the following;

```
Redirect 301 /customer/account/edit/ https://example.com/
Redirect 301 /customer/address/ https://example.com/
Redirect 301 /customer/address/new/ https://example.com/
Redirect 301 /sales/order/history/ https://example.com/
Redirect 301 /customer/account https://example.com/
```

However our log out URL, which is `/customer/account/logout` gets redirected as well. We have tried doing something like;

```
Redirect 301 /customer/account/logout/ https://example.com/customer/account/logout
```

but with the above redirects already in place, that just resulted in `example.com/logout` which doesn't work for the log out functioning.

Any ideas on how to let this subdir url bypass the above 301 rewrites? (We are on Apache if that helps any)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive uses prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. You can use `RedirectMatch` (which uses a regex as opposed to simple prefix-matching) to match a specific URL.

However, since Magento already uses mod_rewrite directives (as part of the front-controller pattern) in `.htaccess` you should use mod_rewrite to avoid unexpected conflicts.

Try the following instead at the top of the `.htaccess` file, before any existing rewrites.

```
RewriteRule ^customer/account/(edit/)?$ / [QSD,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^customer/address/(new/)?$ / [QSD,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sales/order/history$ / [QSD,R=301,L]
```

These 3 directives redirect the 5 URLs as mentioned and all redirect to the homepage, discarding any query string.

However, rather than simply redirect the user to the homepage it may be preferable to display a custom 404 message with a link to the homepage instead?

---

**UPDATE:**

> if I wanted to point these redirects to a specific 404 page (figure `example.com/404.html`), how would we add that ...?

You could do it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteRule ^customer/account/(edit/)?$ / [R=404]
RewriteRule ^customer/address/(new/)?$ / [R=404]
RewriteRule ^sales/order/history$ / [R=404]
```

Although this does change the Apache 404 error document for all requests (although that may not be an issue since Magento generally handles its own 404s and there are ways around this if that is a problem).

(There may also be a more "Magento" specific way to create a custom 404 that can be called from Apache.)

If you are using PHP (eg. `/404.php`) then you could internally rewrite the request to `/404.php` instead, but you need to ensure that `404.php` sets the appropriate 404 Not Found status (HTTP response header). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^customer/account/(edit/)?$ 404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^customer/address/(new/)?$ 404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sales/order/history$ 404.php [L]
```

#### `/404.php`

```
<?php
http_response_code(404);
:
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! These look to be working great. In our particular situation, we are implementing a whole separate customer dashboard so the links that would point to their account and what not will be gone so we would hope no one would be getting to these URLs in the first place, but this is just basically a fallback, that said. For completeness and expanded options, if I wanted to point these redirects to a specific 404 page (figure `example.com/404.html`), how would we add that to the above expressions?

Comment: @ne0nlight I've updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!!